# Execute a command when a device is connected via USB

Tags: linux, backup, bash, automation, udev

I currently have a system that backs up my Linux server onto a USB storage device on `/media/usb`. This all works correctly. However, I actually have 2 drives which we try to swap on a daily basis.

Is there anyway of logging when a USB device was plugged in and a way of using `sendmail` or something similar to send an email to the administrator if the drive hasn't been swapped for 3+ days for example?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is off topic or not, but maybe you could try asking at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could parse /var/log/messages, but I wouldn't.

I'd write a udev rule that ran a script when you connect/disconnect the device.  There's some more information on it [here](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/)

I've copied the salient points in case that site goes down:

> Rule files are stored in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory.
>
> There's some advice from the README in that directory on how to name
>   rule files:
>
> Files should be named xx-descriptive-name.rules, the xx should be
>   chosen first according to the following sequence points:
>
> < 60  most user rules; if you want to prevent an assignment being
>   overriden by default rules, use the := operator.
>
> these cannot access persistent information such as that from vol_id
>
> < 70  rules that run helpers such as vol_id to populate the udev db
>
> < 90  rules that run other programs (often using information in the
>   udev db)
>
> > =90  rules that should run last
>
> The first part of a udev rule is the matching keys. We will use the
>   KERNEL entry from the very top of the chain as well as the idVendor,
>   idProduct, and serial attributes from the device specific information.
>   This will positively identify this particular thumb drive and ignore
>   all others. The kernel argument uses  a question mark as a wild card
>   so that if our drive were mounted on a different node (ie: sda1, sdb1,
>   sdc1, etc.) it could still be identified.

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="13fe", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1f00",
ATTRS{serial}=="50E6920B000AE8"
```

> Now that we have the keys necessary to
>   identify the particular hardware we’re looking for we can add
>   assignment arguments. In our case we added two. The first creates a
>   symlink to this device inside of the /dev/ directory. The second
>   executes a script in our home directory:

```
SYMLINK+="hackaday", RUN+="/home/mike/notify-plugin.sh 'HackaDay Thumbdrive:' 'Connected as: $KERNEL'"
```

> Here is the final rule assembled
>   into one line:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="13fe", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1f00", ATTRS{serial}=="50E6920B000AE8", SYMLINK+="hackaday", RUN+="/home/mike/notify-plugin.sh 'HackaDay Thumbdrive:' 'Connected as: $KERNEL'"
```

> We added this as the only line in our rule file and then
>   restarted udev using these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/81-thumbdrive.rules 
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran with this and it works brilliantly. I just used UDEV to store a time the drive was swapped and in my backup script, it checks that file and pings off and email if it doesn't match my criteria!

Comment: Would it make sense to somehow get udev events and log them into journald?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every time you plug in or disconnect and USB device, a message (or messages) is (are) written in the /var/log/messages. You can easily check those out using the command dmesg. It wouldn´t be entirely unreasonable to poll that file every (x) units
 of time to check for connect/disconnect messages and act accordingly.